# Get XML from NSWebView

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, webview

I have a NSWebView in which there is loaded XML data. I cannot get it with stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString because JavaScript doesn't want to work with XML. How the hell am I supposed to get it? Why is it so annoying difficult to do something so simple? Creating XML from URL won't work.

How do I get XML from NSWebView into a NSString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked it out myself. Thing is that you have to take the xml from WebFrame and not from WebView. You can then convert the data into a string or whatever you need.

```
NSData *xmlData = [[myWebView mainFrame] dataSource] data];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use the WebView? I'd suggest just grabbing the data by itself:

`NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"example.com"]];`

Comment: Yeah, I need to use WebView. I don't know exactly how it works but just loading string or xml straight from url doesn't do it's job.